# Android Studio: dividing/addition

Tags: java, android, sdk

```html
catlogs for answer


of 4sec
05-15 06:46:53.225 16772-16772/com.karanvir.ccc E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: com.karanvir.ccc, PID: 16772
                                                                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5702)
                                                                      at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10896)
                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22546)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5702) 
                                                                      at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10896) 
                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22546) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
                                                                      at com.karanvir.ccc.MainActivity.ons(MainActivity.java:68)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5702) 
                                                                      at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10896) 
                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22546) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
05-15 06:46:53.265 762-17089/? E/android.os.Debug: ro.product_ship = true
05-15 06:46:53.265 762-17089/? E/android.os.Debug: ro.debug_level = 0x4f4c
05-15 06:46:53.265 762-17089/? E/android.os.Debug: sys.mobilecare.preload = false
```

XML FILE

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.karanvir.ccc.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/d">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/achieved3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/achieved2"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textColorLink="@android:color/background_light" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/achieved1"
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/achieved"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textColorLink="@android:color/background_light" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/achieved2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/achieved1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textColorLink="@android:color/background_light" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/total0"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/achieved1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/achieved1"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/of_total"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textColorLink="@android:color/background_light"
            android:text="0"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/total1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/total0"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textColorLink="@android:color/background_light"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/total2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/total1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textColorLink="@android:color/background_light" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText7"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText7"
            android:onClick="ons"
            android:text="@string/press_for_grade_average"
           />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textColorLink="@android:color/background_light"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/achieved4"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:text="0"
            tools:ignore="UnknownId"
            android:layout_below="@+id/achieved3"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/achieved5"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/achieved4"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:text="0" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/achieved6"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/achieved5"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:text="0" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/achieved7"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/total7"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/achieved9"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/achieved9"
            android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:text="0" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/achieved8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/achieved7"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/achieved7"
            android:layout_below="@+id/achieved7"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:text="0" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/achieved9"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/achieved8"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:text="0" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/achieved10"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/achieved9"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:text="0" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/total3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/total2"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:text="0" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/total4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/total3"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/total3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/total3"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:text="0" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/total5"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/total4"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:text="0" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/total6"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/total5"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:text="0" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/total7"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/total6"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/total6"
            android:layout_below="@+id/total6"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:text="0" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/total8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/total7"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/total7"
            android:layout_below="@+id/total7"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:text="0" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/total9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/total8"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/total8"
            android:layout_below="@+id/total8"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:text="0" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Guys this is the code for my app, i want My program to take the achs and the tots . Then divide the tots by the achs. Please take a look below, tell me how I can make this work.They all have a initial value of zero. Im making a grade calculator app I get NaN when i press my button. I am trying to figure out what im doing wrong.I want all my values added then divided . What can I do?

```html
package com.karanvir.ccc;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText number1;
    EditText number2;
    EditText number3;
    EditText number4;
    EditText number5;
    EditText number6;
    EditText number7;
    EditText number8;
    EditText number9;
    EditText number10;
    double ach1;
    double ach2;
    double ach3;
    double ach4;
    double ach5;
    double ach6;
    double ach7;
    double ach8;
    double ach9;
    double ach10;


    EditText answer;
    // setting up our % of grades part
    EditText total0;
    EditText total1;
    EditText total2;
    EditText total3;
    EditText total4;
    EditText total5;
    EditText total6;
    EditText total7;
    EditText total8;
    EditText total9;
    double tot1;
    double tot2;
    double tot3;
    double tot4;
    double tot5;
    double tot6;
    double tot7;
    double tot8;
    double tot9;
    double tot10;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initializeUi();



    }


    private void initializeUi() {

        number1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved1);
        number2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved2);
        number3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved3);
        number4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved4);
        number5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved5);
        number6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved6);
        number7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved7);
        number8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved8);
        number9 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved9);
        number10 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved10);
        ach1 = Integer.parseInt(number1.getText().toString());
        ach2 = Integer.parseInt(number2.getText().toString());
        ach3 = Integer.parseInt(number3.getText().toString());
        ach4 = Integer.parseInt(number4.getText().toString());
        ach5 = Integer.parseInt(number5.getText().toString());
        ach6 = Integer.parseInt(number6.getText().toString());
        ach7 = Integer.parseInt(number7.getText().toString());
        ach8 = Integer.parseInt(number8.getText().toString());
        ach9 = Integer.parseInt(number9.getText().toString());
        ach10 = Integer.parseInt(number10.getText().toString());

//Casting our button and the answer field

        answer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
// setting up our % of grades part
        total0 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total0);
        total1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total1);
        total2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total2);
        total3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total3);
        total4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total4);
        total5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total5);
        total6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total6);
        total7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total7);
        total8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total8);
        total9 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total9);
        tot1 = Integer.parseInt(total0.getText().toString());
        tot2 = Integer.parseInt(total1.getText().toString());
        tot3 = Integer.parseInt(total2.getText().toString());
        tot4 = Integer.parseInt(total3.getText().toString());
        tot5 = Integer.parseInt(total4.getText().toString());
        tot6 = Integer.parseInt(total5.getText().toString());
        tot7 = Integer.parseInt(total6.getText().toString());
        tot8 = Integer.parseInt(total7.getText().toString());
        tot9 = Integer.parseInt(total8.getText().toString());
        tot10 = Integer.parseInt(total9.getText().toString());


    }
    public void ons(View view) {

        double tots = (tot1 + tot2 + tot3 + tot4 + tot5 + tot6 + tot7 + tot8 + tot9 + tot10);
        double achst= ach1+ach2+ach3+ach4+ach5+ach6+ach7+ach8+ach9+ach10;

        double multi = achst / tots;
        String total2 = String.valueOf(multi);
        answer.setText(total2);

    }
}
```

XML FILE

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. In order for folks to be able to help you, please ask a specific question. What is not working in your code? The above is too broad. This is not the Please-do-my-homework-channel.

Comment: please add your layout.xml file too

Comment: Done, take a look at the top

Comment: I get NaN when i press my button. I am trying to figure out what im doing wrong.I want all my values added then divided . It doesnt make sense to me when it runs and doesnt work

Comment: @LiveStream  find the below answer

Comment: sorry the answer is not working

Comment: @LiveStream try now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText number1;
    EditText number2;
    EditText number3;
    EditText number4;
    EditText number5;
    EditText number6;
    EditText number7;
    EditText number8;
    EditText number9;
    EditText number10;
    double ach1;
    double ach2;
    double ach3;
    double ach4;
    double ach5;
    double ach6;
    double ach7;
    double ach8;
    double ach9;
    double ach10;


    EditText answer;
    // setting up our % of grades part
    EditText total0;
    EditText total1;
    EditText total2;
    EditText total3;
    EditText total4;
    EditText total5;
    EditText total6;
    EditText total7;
    EditText total8;
    EditText total9;
    double tot1;
    double tot2;
    double tot3;
    double tot4;
    double tot5;
    double tot6;
    double tot7;
    double tot8;
    double tot9;
    double tot10;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);
        initializeUi();
    }


    private void initializeUi() {
        number1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved1);
        number2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved2);
        number3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved3);
        number4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved4);
        number5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved5);
        number6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved6);
        number7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved7);
        number8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved8);
        number9 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved9);
        number10 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved10);


//Casting our button and the answer field

        answer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
// setting up our % of grades part
        total0 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total0);
        total1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total1);
        total2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total2);
        total3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total3);
        total4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total4);
        total5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total5);
        total6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total6);
        total7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total7);
        total8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total8);
        total9 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total9);
        }

    public void ons(View view) {
        tot1 = Integer.parseInt(total0.getText().toString());
        tot2 = Integer.parseInt(total1.getText().toString());
        tot3 = Integer.parseInt(total2.getText().toString());
        tot4 = Integer.parseInt(total3.getText().toString());
        tot5 = Integer.parseInt(total4.getText().toString());
        tot6 = Integer.parseInt(total5.getText().toString());
        tot7 = Integer.parseInt(total6.getText().toString());
        tot8 = Integer.parseInt(total7.getText().toString());
        tot9 = Integer.parseInt(total8.getText().toString());
        tot10 = Integer.parseInt(total9.getText().toString());

        ach1 = Integer.parseInt(number1.getText().toString());
        ach2 = Integer.parseInt(number2.getText().toString());
        ach3 = Integer.parseInt(number3.getText().toString());
        ach4 = Integer.parseInt(number4.getText().toString());
        ach5 = Integer.parseInt(number5.getText().toString());
        ach6 = Integer.parseInt(number6.getText().toString());
        ach7 = Integer.parseInt(number7.getText().toString());
        ach8 = Integer.parseInt(number8.getText().toString());
        ach9 = Integer.parseInt(number9.getText().toString());
        ach10 = Integer.parseInt(number10.getText().toString());

        double tots = (tot1 + tot2 + tot3 + tot4 + tot5 + tot6 + tot7 + tot8 + tot9 + tot10);
        double achst = ach1 + ach2 + ach3 + ach4 + ach5 + ach6 + ach7 + ach8 + ach9 + ach10;
        double multi = achst / tots;
        String total2 = String.valueOf(multi);
           answer.setText(total2);

    }

}
```

.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.karanvir.ccc.MainActivity">

    <!--<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>-->

    <!-- <include layout="@layout/content_main" />-->

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/achieved3"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/achieved2"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:text="0" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/achieved1"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="achieved"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:text="0" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/achieved2"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/achieved1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:text="0" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/total0"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/achieved1"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/achieved1"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="of_total"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"

                android:text="0" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/total1"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/total0"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:text="0"

                />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/total2"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/total1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:text="0" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText7"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText7"
                android:onClick="ons"
                android:text="press_for_grade_average" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="0"

                />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/achieved4"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/achieved3"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:text="0"
                tools:ignore="UnknownId" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/achieved5"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/achieved4"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:text="0" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/achieved6"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/achieved5"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:text="0" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/achieved7"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/total7"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/achieved9"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/achieved9"
                android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:text="0" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/achieved8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/achieved7"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/achieved7"
                android:layout_below="@+id/achieved7"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:text="0" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/achieved9"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/achieved8"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:text="0" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/achieved10"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/achieved9"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:text="0" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/total3"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/total2"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:text="0" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/total4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/total3"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/total3"
                android:layout_below="@+id/total3"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:text="0" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/total5"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/total4"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:text="0" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/total6"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/total5"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:text="0" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/total7"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/total6"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/total6"
                android:layout_below="@+id/total6"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:text="0" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/total8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/total7"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/total7"
                android:layout_below="@+id/total7"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:text="0" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/total9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/total8"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/total8"
                android:layout_below="@+id/total8"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:text="0" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: ok thank you im going to test this out, also should it be parseInt? shouldnt it be parsedouble since its a double value?

Comment: your answer crashes my app when i press my button, any other fixes?

Comment: @LiveStream show me your logcat's fatal error, which came when your app crashes

Comment: for the sake of testing your code , I had updated it's layout a little bit.. I'll edit my answer and post all the code here.. see if it helps.

Comment: code made setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4); go in bright red?

Comment: Never mind I took out the 4 and now am running. will post errors if any

Comment: yeah, edit names of activity, layout file and package as per your project, As mentioned earlier I altered some of your code for testing

Comment: Thanks it works, I just have one final question if your not to busy. Im trying to make a grade calculator how could i edit the multi variable to achieve this goal? thanks

Comment: what exactly do u mean by "edit the multi variable" ? sorry I am not getting your point.

Comment: so i want to be able to get numbers in the app, one side being weight achieved. the other side being the total weight % of the final grade. In the double multi variable I have made a mathematical equation to find the percentage achieved divided by the assignments weighted. And this equation doesn't work. I was wondering if you knew a equation to make this work so when the user taps the button, the proper % shows

Comment: do you understand ?

Comment: dude this is simple mathematics I guess, you need to calculate % then simply use it's formula.. which is: % =  (obtained/ total) * 100.